# Access Violation Exception

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll, opencv, access-violation

I am having some strange problem. I have written a small module in VC++ using OpenCV.

It works fine. The code aggregates feed from the CCTV camera connected to the USB port.

however, I had to write the rest of my application in C#, so I made a DLL of the VC++ code and called the VC++ method from C#.

Now, I have ended up getting an error

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Can anyone please suggest me any solution to this. Is there any Access Violation while accessing it in a managed code?

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the DLL, and the extern definitions?  I have some thoughts, want to make sure they apply before I answer

Comment: [DllImport("Tracking.dll", EntryPoint = "TrackIt")]
        public extern static IntPtr TrackBlob();
This is the call.
and this is where I am calling
 IntPtr ptr = TrackIt();
                string temp = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
                Marshal.FreeBSTR(ptr);

Comment: which line bombs on you?

Comment: And what is TrackBlob() supposed to be returning?

Comment: When I am calling the DLL method. 
"IntPtr ptr = TrackBlob(); "

Comment: This is the proper code. The earlier one had some mistake in the naming.
[DllImport("Tracking.dll", EntryPoint = "TrackBlob")] public extern static IntPtr TrackBlob(); This is the call. and this is where I am calling IntPtr ptr = TrackBlob(); string temp = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr); Marshal.FreeBSTR(ptr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TrackBlob returns a string, you should be able to define your dllimport as such:

```
[DllImport("Tracking.dll", EntryPoint = "TrackIt")] 
public extern static string TrackBlob();
```

and skip trying to marshal it.

By returning it as an IntPtr, you're trying to get a pointer into memory owned by the unmanaged DLL... returning it as a string will return a copy of the string for you to work with.

Let me know if that works!
James

*** Edit ***

Try one of these:

```
[DllImport("Tracking.dll", EntryPoint = "TrackIt")] 
public extern static [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string TrackBlob();
```

or

```
[DllImport("Tracking.dll", EntryPoint = "TrackIt")] 
public extern static [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] string TrackBlob();
```

Check out this MSDN link on string marshalling:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx

Comment: My dll is actually returning BSTR, since C cannot have Strings. 
I tried your method, keeping the return type in the dll as BSTR. but same error.

Comment: Can you post the C++ method definition?

Comment: Hi, the method definition is huge. It doesn't take any input parameters. Computes the image feed and returns a BSTR.

Comment: Hi, I modified the code and I am getting a new error. The new thread is posted at http://goo.gl/WxNT

Comment: Looks like your other question got answered... hope I was able to help!